# org.json.JSONException: No value for data

Tags: java, android

I try to make a android application but I get title's exception. My first goal is to display in TextView one character from json. After that I would like to go to the next character after click the button.The code is for a school project. I try for hours to find what goes wrong but I can not find the error.I have read a lot of stackoverflow questions and their answers but the answers are sophisticated for every piece of code.

```
package com.example.pirama3.pirama3;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     public List<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
    public String[] ls= new String[3998];




    public void loadGrades(View view){
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.test02);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        parseJson(builder.toString());
    }

    private void parseJson(String s) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try{
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray dt = root.getJSONArray("data");
            for(int i=0;i<3999;i++){
                JSONObject chara = dt.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("aaa",chara.getString("character"));
                ls[i]=chara.optString("character");
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Log.d("abcc",list.get(0));
        //txt.setText(s);
        txt.setText(ls[1]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.abc);

        //Log.d("abcc",list.get(0));
        //System.out.println(list.get(0));Resources res = getResources();
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.test02);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            JSONArray dt = root.getJSONArray("data");
            //ls = new String[dt.length()];
        }catch (JSONException ab){
            ab.printStackTrace();
        }
        txt.setText(ls[1]);

    }

}
```

My json file is like below

```
{
data:[
{
 character:"a",
pronunciation:"a"
},
{
character:"b",
"pronunciation:"b"
}
]
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.pirama3.pirama3.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="loadGrades"
        android:text="@string/button_load_grades"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="@string/text_student_info" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you really have 3998 elements in your list? Or are you just trying reserve sufficient space in your array?

Comment: please add your json response here.

Comment: I really have 3999 elements in my list

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework assignment I will not do all the coding here (your assignment should be good for something).
In general you have some code redundancy here--namely you are parsing your resource file multiple times(every time you click the button). So pack that code into its own method and call it only once--probably best from `onCreate`.

Even if you do know that you will have 3999 elements in your array it is best not to use `public String[] ls= new String[3998];` (Why `public` anyway??)  A `ArrayList` will expand as you need it. So do something like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> list;

private void parseJson(String s) {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray dt = root.getJSONArray("data");
        int len = dt.length();
        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
            JSONObject chara = dt.getJSONObject(i);
            String s = chara.optString("character", "");
            if(!s.isEmpty()){
                list.add(s);
            }
    }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So now you have loaded you data from your resource (do that only once). Load the characters from your resources into an `ArrayList` (do that only once).
Set the initial value of the `TextView`.

Now keep a variable to hold the index of the array position of the value in your `ArrayList` "list" that you are currently displaying.

```
private int currentIndex = 0;
```

Now each time you click the button just increment the value of currentIndex and show that `ArrayList` value in your `TextView`

```
public void loadGrades(View view){
    currentIndex++;
    String s = list.get(currentIndex);
    txt.setText(s);
}
```

**Disclaimer**:: I did this in a text editor, so there may be a couple of misspellings of methods or syntax errors. But you should get the idea.

**Additional Note**: You will probably want to load your resource file in a background thread and load the data Asynchronously.